# How to write a single process class that can be started multiple times?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, multiprocessing, super

I would like to modify the `multiprocessing.Process` class such that it outputs the `stdout` and `stderr` to a given file.

To do so I have written a class wrapper which inherits from `multiprocessing.Process`

```
import sys

class procwrapper(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, logfile, target, args=(), kwargs={}):
        self.logfile = logfile
        super().__init__(target=target, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    def run(self):
        '''
        This runs on self.start() in a new process
        '''
        sys.stdout = open(self.logfile, 'a+')
        sys.stderr = open(self.logfile, 'a+')

        if self._target:
            self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stderr.close()
```

Now I would also like to write this class in such a way that I do not have to recreate it after starting it. To do so I have written the following

```
class Myproc:
    def __init__(self, logfile, target, args=(), kwargs={}):
        self.logfile = logfile
        self.target = target
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def start(self):
        procwrapper(self.logfile, self.target, self.args, self.kwargs).start()
```

---

Somehow this does not feel elegant, is it possible to write them as a single class?

Comment: This should read `super().__init__(target=None, ...` => `self._target = target` => `class Myproc(procwrapper): super.__init__(...` without class attributes and without `def start(...`. As it stands, you don't need `class Myproc` at all.

Comment: @stovfl, I do not want to create a new instance of procwrapper each time i want to start the process. Thus the need for `Myproc`

Comment: You want [Process Pools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=pool#module-multiprocessing.pool)?

Comment: @stovfl, not quite, I want to start the process at certain times, rather than start them simultaneously

Comment: ***I want to start the process at certain times***: Did you meant, *start a task at certain times*, running in the already created `Process` which is not terminating after the task has finished?